# removing parent href attributes of certain div elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table contains rows that contains anchor elements
This anchor elements contains div elements and I want to remove 'href' attributes of certain anhcor whose child div elements class contains 'bg-color-green'.

here is how html looks;

```
<a href="somelink data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tarih Aralığı :
01.02.2014 - 02.03.2014
   Uygulanma Tarihi : 
04.02.2014">
    <div class="well well-sm bg-color-green txt-color-white text-center">
        II
    </div>
</a>
```

and to remove all href attributes of parent anchors I use this;

```
$(".bg-color-green").parent('a').remove('href')
```

but it doesnt work, whats problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeAttr("href")` and not `remove("href")`

also please note that you are missing the end `"` at `href="somelink`

**demo**

```js
$(".bg-color-green").parent('a').removeAttr('href')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelink" data-toggle=" tooltip " title=" " data-original-title="Tarih Aralığı : 01.02.2014 - 02.03.2014 Uygulanma Tarihi : 04.02.2014 ">
  <div class="well well-sm bg-color-green txt-color-white text-center ">
    II
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `href` attr empty with `attr('href','')`.

```js
$(".bg-color-green").parent('a').attr('href','');
console.log($(".bg-color-green").parent('a').attr('href'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelink data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tarih Aralığı :
01.02.2014 - 02.03.2014
   Uygulanma Tarihi : 
04.02.2014">
    <div class="well well-sm bg-color-green txt-color-white text-center">
        II
    </div>
</a>
```

or remove it with [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) function.

```js
$(".bg-color-green").parent('a').removeAttr('href');
console.log($(".bg-color-green").parent('a').attr('href'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="somelink data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Tarih Aralığı :
01.02.2014 - 02.03.2014
   Uygulanma Tarihi : 
04.02.2014">
    <div class="well well-sm bg-color-green txt-color-white text-center">
        II
    </div>
</a>
```